# how to update a file within an ADO pipeline

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to develop a simple pipeline with azure as a bit of a POC.

The aim is to do the following:

- trigger when someone commits an updated json file
- read the json file and identify a "version" attribute and increment it by 1
- write the update file back
- commit the changes back to git

The pipleline appears to trigger correctly and creates a git repo with a detached HEAD in the first step.  This is all standard code from azure.

I've used a simple python script to read the json file, update the attribute and write it back.

What I'm struggling to do is get those changes committed back to the origin git repo, a the minute they just disappear at the end of the pipleline.

I've tried a few things, latest attempt is to use:

`git add ./Content/basic.json`
`git commit -m 'update version number [skip ci]'`
`git push origin Development`
(These are run from the python script using subprocess.run following the update to the json file)

The add and commit appear to work but the push fails with this:

error: src refspec Development does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'url for my source repo'

When I've run git branch commands its seems I can't see any of the branches in either the remote origin repo or the headless clone.

any assistance appreciated, is there an easier way of getting the file changes made in the origin repo?

UPDATE:

I have a repo called "Simple".  This has three branches, main (default) in ADO, Development and Dev.

I'm working in the Development branch in ADO and vscode.  When i make changes to files in the Development branch the pipeline triggers and runs through the following steps:

- initialise job: this is a standard pipeline step
- Checkout Simple@Development to s

this runs a number of git commands that have been autogenerated by Azure. I suspect the output of that step maybe providing the answer, I just don't know what it means.

Here's the git commands and output from that step:

```
==============================================================================

Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.`
Version      : 1.0.0`
Author       : Microsoft`
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)`
==============================================================================
Syncing repository: Simple (Git)
git version
git version 2.43.0
git lfs version
git-lfs/3.4.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.21.1)
git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
git remote add origin <url to repo>
git config gc.auto 0
git config --get-all <url to repo>
git config --get-all http.extraheader
git config --get-regexp .*extraheader
git config --get-all http.proxy
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1 +8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116:refs/remotes/origin/8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116
remote: Azure Repos        
remote: 
remote: Found 13 objects to send. (0 ms)        
From <url to repo>
 * [new ref]         8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116 -> origin/8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116
git --config-env=http.extraheader=env_var_http.extraheader fetch --force --tags --prune --prune-tags --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin --depth=1 +8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116
remote: Azure Repos        
remote: 
remote: Found 0 objects to send. (16 ms)        
From <url to repo>
 * branch            8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116 -> FETCH_HEAD
git checkout --progress --force refs/remotes/origin/8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116
Note: switching to 'refs/remotes/origin/8520646c06ef567d0494494cc5d2dcc70cb76116'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at 8520646 now with a prune
Finishing: Checkout Simple@Development to s
```

I'm thinking the comment towards the end about git switch - c is aimed at helping me.... I'm just unsure what it means and how I'd use it effectively.

I assume I'd do a git switch -c Development before I update the JSON file, then add/commit it.  But how do I get that change back to the origin Development branch, will the push now work?

For completeness other steps in the pipeline are just default ones that I updated with some commands to confirm the default working directory and a call to the python script:

````
YAML
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
   - Development

pool:
   vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
 - script: echo Hello, world!
   displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
  echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
  echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  echo ls -la
  ls -la
  echo ls -la ./Scripts
  ls -la ./Scripts
  echo ls -la ./Scripts/update_json_file.py
  ls -la ./Scripts/update_json_file.py
  which git
 
 displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'


- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Run a python script'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: './Scripts/update_json_file.py'```
````

Comment: @phd `git -m` is commit message.

Comment: sorry typo... my fault the command is: git commit -m 'update version number [skip ci]'

Comment: I'll edit the origainl post and add some details around the existing repos and the pipeline steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any assistance appreciated, is there an easier way of getting the file changes made in the origin repo?

You can change the json file in your python script, and add a new task, use git command to push the file back to the repo. Please notice the comment in the yaml below:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true # This allows later steps to use the system-provided token to execute commands

- script: echo test1 >> basic.json    # you can change the file with python scirpt

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "test@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "test1"
    git add basic.json             # you can use "git add ." to add all files
    git commit -m "Update version number [skip ci]"
    git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  displayName: 'Commit changes'
```

The yaml above use `build service` scoped identity to push the file to repo, hence, please go to `project settings` -> Repositories -> target repo -> security -> grant `contribute` role for the `projectname build servie(orgname)` account.

[image]

[image]

The json file updated:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got there this morning, thank you for your post.  I had tried using a system access token but eventually in researching how to use that spotted something that suggested using the - checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true once I added that my script worked.

Comment: I also had to add the permissions that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You try to publish `Development` branch, which does not exist locally. You have few options there:

- As first step checkout new branch `git checkout -b Development` - it checkouts new branch named `Development`. Then make changes and make commit.
- You can specify which local branch should be pushed to remote: `git push main:Development` - if you work on `main` on CI, you'll push your local (local for CI) branch `main` to your remote `Development` branch.

---

But there probably will be more problems further.

If you look for changes on `main`, and push on `Development` then on second try you'll have conflicts.